# The restful GET route should not work for the controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How I can I forbide that number 1) is executed? I want that only number 2) triggers the Get action because only this route is restful and only the route mapped to the action should trigger the action. At least this is my beginner opinion with Rest and web api...

1) \api\user triggers the Get action.

2) \api\users triggers the Get action.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var userDto = _userService.GetUsers();
        return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<UserDTO>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, userDto);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you seeing the above mentioned action `Get()` is getting selected when you do a `api/user`?

Comment: @KiranChalla With my above code the url /api/user still triggers the Get action.

Comment: what is the version of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` nuget package that you are using?

Comment: <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />

Comment: @KiranChalla I will also post my MapHttpRoute definitions when I am at home later...

Comment: @KiranChalla Sorry I was wrong. When I enter url /api/user I get this message: {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:6320/api/user'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'User' that matches the request."} I do not know what I have changed that it works now...

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess, I would say that you still have the default MapHttpRoute in your config that is using regular ASP.Net routing to route `api/user` to the UserController

Comment: good guess...but ideally this should not work as we intentionally do not allow conventional routes to reach attributed actions or controllers...in this case i would have expected the `Get()` action to not have been selected..